# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array RandomObjectSpawner.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/RandomObjectSpawner.cs:21)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have this script that i am trying to use to spawn random objects in random positions in my game. but i have this error "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. RandomObjectSpawner.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/RandomObjectSpawner.cs:21)"

[image: These are the objects i want to spawn when i click the middle bush]

this is the script i'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] myObjects;



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))

        {

            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, myObjects.Length);
            Vector3 randomSpawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10, 11), 5, Random.Range(-10, 11));

            Instantiate(myObjects[randomIndex], randomSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
             
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate `myObjects`? What is the length of the array when `Random.Range` is called?

Comment: i didn't put any number for the length

Comment: So your array has no elements? Again, where do you set the value of `myObjects`? You can't exactly get an element from an array when you either don't create the array or you don't give the array any elements.

Comment: i have 15 objects to spawn and set them up into the script that i added to the spawner object

Comment: @gunr2171 i added a picture you can see the objects i want to spawn and that i added them to the script

Comment: Are they also assigned when you hit play?

Comment: yes i play in the heirarchy they are spawnning when i press the mouse button but the error stays there even when the items are spawned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a wild hunch. I guess your script is attached to multiple game objects and in one of them the game objects are not assigned to the array. so check all other game objects to see if `RandomObjectSpawner` is not assigned to any other `gameobject`.

Comment: you were right i forgot i added it to the left bush and the right bush too because i want 3 of the bushes to spawn the herbs on press. thank you so much

Comment: another thing is that i don't see the items in the surface when  they're spawned. but i will figure it out. thank you

Comment: @kyloriusbeno no problem, if you have other problems make another question and ask separately

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing your array like this and see if the problem happens again:

```
 public GameObject[] myObjects = new GameObject[] { };
```

Alternatively you can attach your debugger to Unity, set a breakpoint to this line:

```
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, myObjects.Length);
```

And see step by step (1) what's the index that has been generated, (2) what the actual length of the array is.

Comment: Failure to initialize the array would cause a Null Reference Exception, not an Index Out of Range Exception, and the array you just created can't hold any elements anyway.

Comment: In Unity you can do that, as you put the objects in the Inspector and it initializes the array with its correct length. 

As for the NullReference you are right, but since I don't see anything wrong with his code, I am assuming there's something behind that's not fully working here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it seems that he found the solution. The script was attached to multiple GOs and in one of them the array was empty.